# How to use Spring Managed Hibernate Session in Seam?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0, seam2

Most recent project I working where I trying to use Spring (3.1.1.RELEASE) Managed Hibernate Session into Seam (2.3.0.Final).

In JBoss Seam Documentation where they explain [How to use Seam Managed Hibernate Session in Spring](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Seam_Reference_Guide/spring-hibernate.html). But our requirement is invert than the documentation.

I got another solution [Using Spring PlatformTransactionManagement](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Seam_Reference_Guide/spring-transactions.html) but my requirement is use Spring Managed Hibernate Session in Seam. I don't want to use Seam manage Hibernate Session/Hibernate Entity Manager/Transaction. Only want to use Seam manage dependency injection to inject Spring bean into Seam manage bean via seam `@In` not Spring `@Autowire`.

If anybody faces such type of challenge please either help to configure Seam `components.xml` & Spring `applicationContext.xml` or provide me guide line to overcome this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Configure `applicationContext.xml` as usually you configured:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <!-- hibernate Properties Here -->                     
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

Then Configure `components.xml` as following:

```
<core:init debug="true" transaction-management-enabled="true" />
<spring:context-loader config-locations="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"/>
<core:manager concurrent-request-timeout="500" conversation-timeout="120000" conversation-id-parameter="cid" parent-conversation-id-parameter="pid" />
<persistence:managed-hibernate-session name="hibernateSession" auto-create="true" session-factory="#{sessionFactory}"/>
<spring:spring-transaction platform-transaction-manager="#{transactionManager}"/>
```

Its very much easy to interact Spring(3.1.1.RELEASE) with Seam (2.3.0.Final) but never forget to configure `web.xml` for seam.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamResourceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

For facelets your should add variable resolver in `faces-config.xml`

```
<application>
    <variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver</variable-resolver>
</application>
```

Better to download [Seam-2.3.0.Final](http://www.seamframework.org/Seam2/Downloads). Uzip it, inside `examples\spring\` folder you will got your desired configuration